# How to allow files to be accessed by scripts but not the internet - Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions

I wish to set up an apache server running php. I want all the files in a particular folder (say /site/ ) to be accessible from www.example.com/ . However I wish the files in /site/data/ to be not visible through www.example.com/data/ . I want www.example.com/fun.php script to be able to read/write to /site/data/ . What is the best way to do this through premissions and the apache defalt file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up your directory structure slightly differently to what you have proposed. Rather run your site under a directory like:

```
/site/html
```

and store your data under a directory like:

```
/site/data
```

configuring Apache to only serve files from /site/html and not /site/data

or if you are using a more traditional apache directory structure then put the files you want publicly accessible through the web server in:

```
/var/www/html
```

and the private data files you only want your application to have access to in something like:

```
/var/www/data
```

Your Apache conf file will then contain something like:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This way the files in /var/www/data will not be publicly accessible but these files can still be accessed by php scripts in /var/www/html/

Comment: Thanks for your help. It has clarified my understanding as well as giving me a bit of a kick up the bum to do what I thought I should do to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Apache directory listings by putting this in your .htaccess file under /site/data

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: This stops the listing of files but the files are still accessible, not what was asked.